# IDE SharpDevelop ¿donde se encuentra el diseñador?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ide

Hola estoy usando sharp develop ya que es más rapido que visual studio pero mi problema es que no veo el diseñador de mi formulario por ejemplo. Estuve buscando pero sigo sin encontrarlo, os muestro una captura para enseñaros que no me aparece el diseñador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito saber como podría ver el diseño de mi formulario y editarlo con las herramientas que normalmente uno usa en visual studio.

Me pasa mas bien cuando creo un proyecto en visual basic con windows form en c# se visualiza perfectamente el formulario.

Comment: estas seguro que este ide es mas rapido que el VS ? puede ser un poco pero las tool que el VS tiene no creo que las tengas con este ide.

Comment: usa el mismo compilador

Comment: de todos modos todavía esta en construcción es una alternativa pero al ser open source puede que en poco tiempo avance más a visual studio y sea una alternativa verdaderamente estable, aún así requiere todavía más mejoras en mi opinión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He programado usando como **IDE** `Xamarin`, `SharpDevelop`. Pero nunca dejo `Visual Studio`, es cierto que los 2 anteriores son un poco más ligeros. `SharpDevelop` es lo que más se me parece a `Visual Studio`.

> Aquí te dejo una vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si visual studio es muy bueno pero la gente que empieza a programar da mas importancia a veces al ide que al código cuando el código es lo más importante a veces el ide no es tan necesario como pensamos o al menos es mi opinion pero eso si para un trabajo profesional probablemente sin dudarlo visual studio

Answer (score 0):

En el sitio del ide que mencionas

[icsharpcode](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/Default.aspx)

se visualiza el diseñador.

Ahora bien no veo en la imagen que la clase `MainForm` herede de `Form`, por lo tanto no tiene el Designer.vb dodne se especificas los controles del form.

Recomendaria crear un nuevo form con este IDE para ver si visualizas el diseñador del form, porque esta claro que el codigo que quieres editar no parece ser un forma valido